# Jenkins - "docker login" on staging server with jenkins credential

Tags: docker, security, jenkins, deployment, jenkins-pipeline

After pushing to git I want Jenkins to build and deploy the new version of my software (docker image) to a staging environment immediately.

I can make it work but I feel there should be a better way of doing this, especially pulling and running the docker image on the staging server.

How I do it now:

1. multistage docker build and publish to my private registry
2. copy a secret file (managed in Jenkins credentials) to the Jenkins workspace
3. copy the secret file from the Jenkins workspace to the staging server with sshTransfer
4. cat secretFile >> docker login my.private.registry --password-stdin

The problems with this (those that I see, there are probably more)

- 2-4 ist just to hide the docker password from history entries, instead of that I have those files that could be read (especially if I forget to delete them afterward)
- In sshTransfer execCommand runs in a different directory than copying files. Therefore I need to hardcode the absolute path to the copied secret file in the execCommand. So I would have to change the jenkinsfile if I change the "Remote Directory" in the SSHPublisher config.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Jenkins credentials store directly. Just create a credential with the username and password and add this to your pipeline.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '<credentials-id>', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'username')]) {
    sh "docker login -u $username -p $password ..."
}
```

It will hide the password automatically.

Comment: You mean it will not only hide it in any jenkins log but also takes care for all logs/history on the remote server?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I never bothered to actively look for any security problems but the jenkins credentials seem to work pretty well. I am sure there are more details out there you can check